# Get typedef from parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a struct of this form:

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    using value = T;
};
```

I am passing one or more of these to a template function like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void Func(Ts... ts);
```

What I really want is to explicitly list the `X`s and have the function parameter types be the `value`s of the `Ts`.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    using value = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct Y
{
    using value = T*;
};

template <typename... Ts>
void Func(typename Ts::value... ts)
{
}

int main()
{
   Func<X<int>, Y<double>>(10, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Ah, it makes so much sense :D Very nice.